# Specifying requestfocus flag for an edit text with monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to set give a text edit the reqeust focus flag through a layout file this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/etEditText1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10">
         <requestfocus />
    </EditText>
</LienarLayout>
```

The problem is that Visual Studio complains that I can't use  there. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two things to note here:

1. Just because Visual Studio shows a warning in the XML doesn't mean there's actually a problem. The schema provided for AXML documents is simply to aid in providing basic intellisense, but is not 100%. In this case, if you compile and run the app, you'll find that it actually works as expected.
2. There is, however, an actual problem with your XML. Your closing LinearLayout tag is misspelled which will trigger a build error. Updating it to `</LinearLayout>` will fix this.